# Is there a way to copy one file to another location automatically?

Tags: powershell, vim, visual-studio-code, cygwin

For example, guess I have one configure in this file,

```
d:\Users\jonghyun\Documents\configure.txt
```

And the other folder is existed like this.

```
d:\ConfigureViewer\configureView.txt
```

I want to make sure that every time upper file is changed, the other file also would be updated at the same time, same text.

What is the natural way to implement this?

Any way is appreciated - using powershell command, cygwin, vscode

Comment: Easy with a taskrunner and a watcher.  Are you open to gulp for example?  I don't know enough about powershell to help there.

Comment: Use symbolic links?

Comment: Use a FileSystemWatcher: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b

Comment: Symbolic link is shallow copy. I want to deep copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(On windows) You can use Robocopy (built-in in windows).
It has 2 switches for what you ask:

> /mon:  Monitors the source, and runs again when more than N changes
>   are detected.
>   /mot:  Monitors source, and runs again in M minutes
>   if changes are detected.

here is a link to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

Comment: It seems great. What is the difference between fsutil hardlink?

Comment: Robocopy copies the data on change, the hardlink will have only one physical representation on disk.

Comment: In a hardlink you have 1 copy of the file/s (linked from 2 locations on the filesystem),   robocopy have 2 copies of the file

Answer (score 3):

You could create a hardlink if you have a NTFS filesystem:

```
fsutil hardlink create <destination filename> <source filename>
```

So for your example:

```
fsutil hardlink create d:\ConfigureViewer\configureView.txt d:\Users\jonghyun\Documents\configure.txt
```

Comment: exactly what i want